# Join 2 ggplots on the same y-axis? (Titration curve)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a titration curve like this one here, but without the negative sign on the right sided labels: [Titration_Curve_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRiqL.jpg)

I want the right part of my x-axis to show the Volume of "NaOH" and the left part to show the volume of "H2SO4" - with a reversed axis. My problem is that I don't know how to create such a separated x-axis or alternatively how to join both graphs that I have so far generated:

```
pH_acid =  Volume_pH%>%
            filter(Titrant == "H2SO4")
pH_base = Volume_pH%>%
           filter(Titrant == "NaOH")
  
 
plot_acid = ggplot(pH_acid) + aes(x = Volume_titrant, y = pH) + scale_x_reverse() +geom_point()
plot_base = ggplot(pH_base) + aes(x = Volume_titrant, y = pH) + geom_point()
```

I tried to work with conditionals in the aes() function in order to establish different axis in dependence of the Titrant, but only received error codes of all sorts.

Here is some example data, which represents the tibble "Volume_pH" in the above code.

````
Titrant Volume_titrant    pH
  <chr>            <dbl> <dbl>
1 H2SO4                0  4.65
2 H2SO4                1  4.42
3 H2SO4                2  4.32
4 H2SO4                3  4.25
5 H2SO4                4  4.15
6 H2SO4                5  4.11
7 H2SO4                6  3.93
8 H2SO4                7  3.88
9 H2SO4                8  3.74
10 H2SO4                9  3.75
11 H2SO4               10  3.69
12 H2SO4               11  3.55
13 H2SO4               12  3.51
14 H2SO4               13  3.4 
15 H2SO4               14  3.33
16 H2SO4               15  3.26
17 H2SO4               16  3.22
18 H2SO4               17  3.16
19 H2SO4               18  3.11
20 H2SO4               19  3.07
21 H2SO4               20  3.01
22 H2SO4               21  2.98
23 NaOH                 0  4.32
24 NaOH                 1  4.43
25 NaOH                 2  4.54
26 NaOH                 3  4.58
27 NaOH                 4  4.73
28 NaOH                 5  4.82
29 NaOH                 6  4.83
30 NaOH                 7 NA   
31 NaOH                 8  5.11
32 NaOH                 9 NA   
33 NaOH                10  5.38
34 NaOH                11 NA   
35 NaOH                12  5.84
36 NaOH                13 NA   
37 NaOH                14  6.77
38 NaOH                15  7.23
39 NaOH                16  7.92
40 NaOH                17 NA   
41 NaOH                18  8.77
42 NaOH                19  9   
43 NaOH                20  9.15
44 NaOH                21  9.3 
45 NaOH                22 NA   
46 NaOH                23  9.63
47 NaOH                24 NA   
48 NaOH                25  9.7 
49 NaOH                26 NA   
50 NaOH                27  9.98
51 NaOH                28 NA   
52 NaOH                29 10.1 
> ```
````

Comment: Thanks both, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carlo, your thinking was not too bad. With `[ggplot}` you can "overwrite" your axis-tick labels to your liking. With this strategy you can "combine" the plot as shown by @Ian Campbell working with positive and negative xaxis values.
Note: Based on the data, the Volume_titrant column is of type double, thus, use scale_x_continuous(). You could work with factors (scale_x_discrete()).

I set the colour of the points to make sure NaOH is on the "right" side. Adapt the xaxis as appropriate. You can remove the colour setting or replace it with different shapes.

```
# generate xaxis values
## let's add another column to keep "original" xaxis values, in case we need them
Volume_pH <- Volume_pH %>% 
   mutate(xaxis = if_else(Titrant == "H2SO4", -Volume_titrant, Volume_titrant)) 

# plot
Volume_pH %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = xaxis, y = pH)) +

##----------------- point layer --------------------------------------------------
    geom_point(aes(colour = Titrant)) +   # check NaOH on the right side, remove 

##----------------- xaxis ----------------
## we use all breaks from our df and make them positive with the abs() function
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = Volume_pH$xaxis, labels = abs(Volume_pH$xaxis)) +

##----------------- vertical line
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0) + 

##----------------- theme settings
    theme_bw() +                      # white box, use other theme or adjust to your liking
    labs(x = "Volume H2SO4 / NaOH")   # labels & axis text
```

The example comes with "many" breaks. You can tailor them to what type of break level you would like to see on your graph/what makes sense.
Just provide a vector of similar length for the labels to overwrite the (negative) axis ticks. This way you can avoid overlapping x-axis values for the tick marks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for?

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
Volume_pH %>%
  mutate(Volume_titrant = case_when(Titrant == "H2SO4" ~ -Volume_titrant,
                                    TRUE ~ Volume_titrant)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Volume_titrant, y = pH)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) + 
  scale_x_reverse() + 
  labs(x = expression(paste(Volume~(mL)~NaOH~"/"~H[2],SO[4])))
```

[image]

And if you want to get rid of that nasty outlier and add a line:

```
Volume_pH %>%
  mutate(Volume_titrant = case_when(Titrant == "H2SO4" ~ -Volume_titrant,
                                    TRUE ~ Volume_titrant)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(pH) & pH != 4.65) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Volume_titrant, y = pH)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) + 
  scale_x_reverse() + 
  labs(x = expression(paste(Volume~(mL)~NaOH~"/"~H[2],SO[4])))
```

[image]